# Read tabular separated data and show in text boxes (C#, Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, textbox

i'm working on a debugging program for our UAV at work. It's logging flight information data (like a black box) in a tabular separated textfile (.txt) and i wan't some of this data to be shown in the program for easier reading.

This is how i want the program to work:

1. User opens txt file by button
2. User can go through the flights log lines by dragging the trackbar
3. As user scrolls through the log lines, the text boxes update with data from the relevant flight sensors.

The logfiles log 175 different sensors/values. The first 175 sets of text is headlines and from there on, there is 175 pieces of data before you meet the data from the same category again.

Example: If i want to read avx Throttle, the headline "avx Throttle" is the 18th set. 175 sets later i get the first throttle-value, 175 sets later i get the next value and so on.

**My problem:
How do i make sure that my text boxes only grabs the right pieces of data?**

1. Can i make it "count" the number of Tabs before writing the value in the text box?
2. Would it be better to convert the text file to a more database-friendly file type like .CSV, .XLSX or some other type?
3. If yes, would i be able to make the text box grab the value from a certain column in a table(Like the S-column(avx Throttle) in the Excel picture)? I imagine that would make the job easier?

**See what i'm talking about ->**
[Image of the program, the raw log file and the log file when opened in Excel](http://peecee.dk/uploads/092015/black_box_data_image.png)

I hope you can guide me in the right direction! :)

Sincerely, Morten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove the whitespace/tabs you will need to either replace them or split by them. Here are a few options for getting rid of the tabs/white space

```
string s = dataText.Replace("\t", ",");
```

then you could split it using

```
string[] arrayOfData = s.Split(new char{','};
```

Or if it is white space you could do

```
string s = dataText.Replace(" ", ",");
```

then you could split it using

```
string[] arrayOfData = s.Split(new char{','};
```

if you need to go through the array of values you can use a for loop and based off the column you need you would do something along the lines of this

```
for(int i=0; i < arrayOfData.Length; i++){
     if(columnYouWant){
       //manipulate data arrayOfData[i]
     }
```

you could maybe also do a DataTable and make virtual tables to manipulate you data.